# Angular won't put data objects into array

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am trying to fetch data from an API that looks like this:

[image]

The data is succesfully fetched and I can log it on my console like this:

component.ts:

```
getRacvaData(id:number){
    this.racvaStat=[];
    this.service.GetRacvaPodaci(id).subscribe(data => {console.warn(data)});
}
```

service.ts

```
 GetRacvaPodaci(racvaId: number)
 {
  return this.http.get('http://11.112.3.160:8888/Racve/api/v1/getRacva?racva_id='+racvaId);
 }
```

console:
[image]

But, when I try to put it in a variable and, for example, log that variable or smth, it doesnt give any result. I put the data in a variable like this:

```
public racvaStat:any = [];

getRacvaData(id:number){
    this.racvaStat=[];
    this.service.GetRacvaPodaci(id).subscribe(data => this.racvaStat = data);

    for(let item of this.racvaStat){
      console.log(item.nit_a); // this is not logging anything
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem here? I want to put it in the array so I can use that array all over my project.

Comment: Try this
`this.service.GetRacvaPodaci(id).subscribe((data:any) => {
this.racvaStat = data;
console.log(this.racvaStat)
for(let item of data){
      console.log(item.nit_a);
    }
});`

Comment: Your service is asynchronous meaning you are trying to loop over an array that has not yet been assigned the returned values. If you want to make sure the data has been assigned from your service you should do your operations inside the subscribe block as @RaviAshara mentioned above

Comment: But I want to put the data in the array so I can use that array all over my project, in other funcions/methods/etc...

Comment: @Sam how can I use this.racvaStat outside the subscribe block?

Comment: @OmarLittle you can just use `this.racvaStat`, as long as you use this value after your service has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Because fetching your data is a `Async` task, while you are logging the array content after the HTTP request, without telling JS to wait until the response is received form the API...

you should try smth like ...

```
this.service.GetRacvaPodaci(id).subscribe(data => {
    this.racvaStat = data

    for(let item of this.racvaStat){
      console.log(item.nit_a); // this is not logging anything
    }
});
```

This way the `foreach` will only start when the response is ready inside `racvaStat` array.

I suggest you check out this for more info ..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Okay, that it functional, but what I want to know is what must I do to use this.racvaStat array and all of it's objects outside the subscribe block? My goal is to call getRacvaData() on ngOnInit so it fills up this.racvaStat array and use that array on other methods/functions after.

Comment: If your workflow doesn't require `racvaStat` to be defined after ngOnInit, then it's safe to use this approach, and whenever you called `this,racvaStat` later you should have it defined, if you must wait for it you can use smth like `async/await` ... 
though it's not a good idea since ngOnInit is the first life cycle hook and you are forcing it to stop the component initializing until the response arrive ...